# routes.rb - Controller name not supported

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

I'm having quite a peculiar issue. This is the portion of routes.rb it relates to:

```
resources :players
match '/players/:userid', :to => 'Players#show'
```

When you visit localhost:3000/players/1234 it gives this error:

> 'Players' is not a supported controller name. This can lead to potential routing problems.

The related code in the controller:

```
def show
  begin
    if Player.find_by(:uid => :userid) then
      @playerattributes = Player.find_by(:uid => :userid) 
      if player[:profile_complete] == true then
        @playerinfo = {
            :age => player[:age],
            :team => player[:team],
            :position => player[:position]
        }
      else
        @playerinfo = 0 
      end
    end
    player = Player.find_by(:uid => :userid)[:info]
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
    redirect_to root_url        
    end
end
```

The problem doesn't end there. When the page does load (which it sometimes randomly works), this line acts up:
`if Player.find_by(:uid => :userid) then`
Using PostgreSQL, and the query gets displayed. Instead of using the :userid value from the URL (i.e. localhost:3000/players/1234 would be 1234), it just inputs the text "userid".

Am I missing something obvious?

Really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Change: **P**layers to **p**layers so:

```
match '/players/:userid', :to => 'Players#show'
```

to

```
match '/players/:userid', :to => 'players#show'
```

[Read more](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html).

To read user id value in your controller, use `params[:userid]`, not just `:userid`.

Comment: Better still use :id instead of :userid, to have easier restful redirections (eg redirect_to @player, link_to "...", @player)

Comment: I can't use :id in this case. :userid refers to the id of the associated account with a different service (I'm not handling the login credentials). If I could use :id, I agree, and I would've.

Comment: You must mean :uid in your model, :userid is just a parameter, you might as well name it :manchesterunited

Comment: Yes. Mistyped there :)

Answer (score 2):

Rails individual routes is going to write in this way.

EG:  requested action  "browser url_name(whatever you want)", to:

```
'controller_name#method_name'
```

In your case it should be:

```
match  '/players/:userid', :to => 'players#show'
```

Similarly for a get request:

```
get  '/players/:userid', :to => 'players#show'
```